# mapping items in a matrix with items in a cell array

Tags: matlab, matrix, dictionary, label, match

I have a single column matrix `A` which contain list of times like,

```
1710
1760
2022
2300
2456
2687
3398
3480
3767
3846
5493
5678
5976
7562
7789
7800
8456
9256
9432
9684
12882
13456
16789
```

and a `cell` array `B` that contains time periods and labels (starttime endtime label)

```
1708    2392    +
3394    3660    +
5490    5743    +
7555    7809    -
9256    9509    -
12878   15066   -
```

I want to find the label for each item in `A` and write that as a new matrix. So I need to check each item in `A` and compare it with the start time and end time in `B` and if it belongs to a time limit given there I can write the label (+/-) in matrix `C` and if it is not there I can write 0 there. How to do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `bsxfun` to compare `A` to start time and end time in `B`:

```
startTime = vertcat( B{:,1} ); % assuming B is 6x3 cell array
endTime = vertcat( B{:,2} );
sel = bsxfun( @ge, A', startTime ) & bsxfun( @le, A', endTime ); % check valid interval
[valid inIdx] = max( sel, [], 1 );
```

`valid` is either 1 (for elements in `A` falling inside one of the intervals in `B`), or 0. For those elements of `A` for which `valid` is 1, the corresponding value of `inIdx` will give you the interval index (1 to 6).

Comment: I get the following error while using bsxfun:

Error using bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must
match each other.

Comment: Does the error occur because the cell array is not 6x3 in what I tried the code with?

Comment: @chris for `bsxfun` to work in this case `A` must be a column vector and it is transposed when passed to `bsxfun`. The second argument must be a column vector as well. Both 1D in this case.

Comment: I want to perform the same for larger matrices, when I use it on a 191x3 matrix for Bit produces the Singleton error

Comment: I get the following values when I run the code. 
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
1
13
3
1
4
4
4
1
5
5
1
6
6
7
The trouble now is that even if a value doesn't belong to the timeframe in matrix b it is assigned to one value saying it belong to the the timeframe of 1-7 in matrix B. I want it to indicate 0 or someother means when the values doesnt belong to any timeframes given

Comment: Solved that created and empty timeframe and now that times taht doesnot belong to given timeframes are given that number